# Getting macports django and python to work together

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm a webdeveloper and I have a django project that I need to work on.

I am running mac OSX 10.6.5 on a macbook pro. I used macports to install django and python 2.6.

I now have some sort of problem, possibly related to my PATH / PYTHONPATH that prevents me from running django.

In terminal echo $PATH gives:

```
echo $PATH
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

and echo $PYTHONPATH gives nothing.

sudo port installed gives :

```
sudo port installed
The following ports are currently installed:
autoconf @2.65_1 (active)
automake @1.11.1_0 (active)
bash-completion @1.1_8
bash-completion @1.2_0 (active)
bzip2 @1.0.5_3+darwin
bzip2 @1.0.6_0 (active)
db46 @4.6.21_6 (active)
expat @2.0.1_0
expat @2.0.1_1 (active)
fontconfig @2.8.0_0+macosx (active)
freetype @2.3.12_0+macosx (active)
gdbm @1.8.3_2 (active)
gettext @0.18_0
gettext @0.18.1.1_2 (active)
gperf @3.0.4_0 (active)
help2man @1.38.2_0 (active)
ImageMagick @6.6.2-0_0+q16 (active)
jpeg @8a_0 (active)
lcms @1.19_2 (active)
libiconv @1.13.1_0 (active)
libpng @1.2.43_0 (active)
libtool @2.2.6b_1+darwin (active)
libxml2 @2.7.7_0 (active)
m4 @1.4.14_0 (active)
ncurses @5.7_0+darwin_10
ncurses @5.7_1 (active)
ncursesw @5.7_0+darwin_10
ncursesw @5.7_1 (active)
openssl @1.0.0b_0 (active)
p5-locale-gettext @1.05_2 (active)
p7zip @9.04_0 (active)
perl5 @5.8.9_0 (active)
perl5.8 @5.8.9_3 (active)
pkgconfig @0.25_0 (active)
py26-distribute @0.6.14_0 (active)
py26-django @1.2.3_0+bash_completion (active)
python26 @2.6.6_0+no_tkinter (active)
readline @6.1.002_0 (active)
sqlite3 @3.7.3_0 (active)
tiff @3.9.2_3+macosx (active)
xorg-bigreqsproto @1.1.0_0 (active)
xorg-inputproto @2.0_0 (active)
xorg-kbproto @1.0.4_0 (active)
xorg-libice @1.0.6_0 (active)
xorg-libsm @1.1.1_0 (active)
xorg-libX11 @1.3.3_0 (active)
xorg-libXau @1.0.5_0 (active)
xorg-libXdmcp @1.0.3_0 (active)
xorg-libXext @1.1.1_0 (active)
xorg-libXt @1.0.8_0 (active)
xorg-util-macros @1.7.0_0 (active)
xorg-xcmiscproto @1.2.0_0 (active)
xorg-xextproto @7.1.1_0 (active)
xorg-xf86bigfontproto @1.2.0_0 (active)
xorg-xproto @7.0.16_0 (active)
xorg-xtrans @1.2.5_0 (active)
zlib @1.2.5_0 (active)
```

and when I type python I get:

```
python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'm pretty certain that this is the incorrect version.

When I try and test if django is available to python I get:

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>>
```

Could anyone help me figure out what is going on here? I only need to get django running so that I can view and work on the django project that my colleague sent me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First, Macports writes the file ~/.profile to set its PATH variables. If you have created a ~/.bash_profile file then ~/.profile will be **ignored**. You will have to copy the contents over.

To see what python version Macports has selected use:

```
port select --list python
```

which will show you something like this:

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python32
```

To tell Macports to use a specific version use:

```
port select --set python python27
```

That should get your python version correct. You can use the python easy_install to install Django now or use the Macports distribution of Django.

Comment: I just installed Django via MacPorts (OSX 10.10), and could not get Python to find it (import error). After running `port select --list python`, I saw that "none" was (active), so I used the command you provided and now I can import no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is that really the Python interpreter installed by macports? 2.6.1 smells like the Apple provided one to me (2.6.1 is quite old).

try,

```
which python
```

As an aside, I wouldn't install Django using macports.

EDIT: Macports installed 2.6.6, the problem is the apple provided python is earlier on your path.

```
python26 @2.6.6_0+no_tkinter (active)
```

EDIT:

I use python from homebrew, which by default goes in /usr/local/bin/python.

To use this, I have a line in my .bashrc, but it could go at the end of your /etc/profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

What that does is prepends my system path with location of my homebrew installs (/usr/local)

In your case, it should be where your macports python (the 2.6.6 one) can be found.

HTH

Comment: which python

gives :

    which python
    /usr/bin/python

What would I do to rectify the problem? Create a new path?

Comment: I removed the python part of the path, now I get : echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: I use homebrew not macports, but my "which python" is /usr/local/bin/python. Where do you set your path? I have this in my .bashrc: export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH: (will update my answer for you)

Answer (score 1):

Both Python 2.6.1 and 2.6.6 should work fine with django.  But if you want to use 2.6.6, just add the location of that to your PATH variable now that you've taken the older python off of your path.

To get Django working, try putting the location of django on your PYTHONPATH.  On a mac, if django is installed in /Library/Django-1.2.1 add:
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Django-1.2.1`
to your ~/.bash_profile file.  (then run `source ~/.bash_profile` to refresh it).

If that doesn't work, I would re-install django. I've never used macports, but installing python packages with pip has always worked well for me.  Delete your old django files and run `easy-install pip` and then `pip -install django` should do the trick - that will install django in your site-packages directory, so it will be on your path and ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out, after running

```
sudo port install py26-django
```

You have two different python environments.

You end up python2.6 installed and symlinked from /opt/local/bin/python2.6, but this directory doesn't have "python", just "python2.6". So when you run "python", you still pick up the default python installation.

To fix the issue, do

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s python2.6 python
```

Since /opt/local/bin is first on your PATH, running "python" would pick-up the environment installed by macport.